# How to delete a sub directory containing a sub-directory and text files

Tags: vb.net

I want to delete a subdirectory that has another sub-directory which contains text files. The code I am using is:

```
Dim Nb = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Student List\" & TextBox10.Text))
Dim Gt As String = Path.Combine(Nb.FullName)
System.IO.File.Delete(Gt)
```

This doesn’t work for me. Please how can I re-write this? I am using VB 2010 Express. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete Folders and Containing Files - VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241673/delete-folders-and-containing-files-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim Nb = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Student List\" & TextBox10.Text))
    Try
        If Directory.Exists(Nb.FullName) Then
            Dim oDirectory As New DirectoryInfo(Nb.FullName)
            If oDirectory.GetFiles.Count > 0 Then
                For Each oFile As FileInfo In oDirectory.GetFiles
                    oFile.Delete()
                Next
            End If
            If oDirectory.GetDirectories.Count > 0 Then
                For Each oDir As DirectoryInfo In oDirectory.GetDirectories
                    oDir.Delete(True)
                Next
                Nb.Delete()
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `File.Delete(path)` use `Directory.Delete(path, true)` the true refers to recursively deleting the contents of the directory and sub-directories.