# code to delete folder with subfolders containing subfolders too

Tags: vb.net

I need code to delete a whole folder including all it's files, subfolders and all subfolders in the subfolders as well and may contain readonly files. For example: i have a folder C:\Test\Test2\Test3\Test4. The folder C:\Test chould no more exist after executing the code.

Comment: This is not a proper way to ask a question, besides it's like the first result when you search on it for google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete Folders and Containing Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241673/delete-folders-and-containing-files)

Comment: The first search on google gives only deleting subfolders but no subfolders in these subfolders, so unusable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try This out..

```
Dim del As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Test")
del.Delete(True)
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for, the only thing i miss is it can not delete readonly files (sorry was forgotten to mention that)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help

```
Process.Start("CMD", "/C RD C:\Test /Q /S")
```

OR

```
Shell("CMD /C RD C:\Test /Q /S", AppWinStyle.MinimizedFocus, True)
```